# Error when trying to remove Lease from file using Azure Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-storage-account

I'm facing some issues when trying to break a lease on file in Azure Storage Account using the code below.

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, AzureCliCredential, ChainedTokenCredential, ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, BlobLeaseClient
import datetime

dbutils.widgets.text('client_id', '')
dbutils.widgets.text('tenant_id', '')
dbutils.widgets.text('lake_secret', '')
client_id = dbutils.widgets.get('client_id')
tenant_id = dbutils.widgets.get('tenant_id')
lake_secret = dbutils.widgets.get('lake_secret')

azure_secret_credentials = ClientSecretCredential(client_secret=lake_secret, client_id=client_id, tenant_id=tenant_id)
credential = ChainedTokenCredential(AzureCliCredential(), azure_secret_credentials)
token = credential.get_token('.default')


api_version = '2023-08-03'
request_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
headers = {
    'x-ms-date' : request_time,
    'x-ms-version' : api_version,
    'Authorization' : azure_secret_credentials.get_token('https://storage.azure.com/.default'),
    "x-ms-lease-action": "break",
    "x-ms-version": "2021-12-02",
    "Accept": "application/xml"
}

account_url = "<url>"
bsc = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credential)
bc = bsc.get_blob_client('lake', '<path>')
blc = BlobLeaseClient(bc)
blc.break_lease(0, headers=headers)
```

As a result I get the message below:

```
HttpResponseError: (MissingRequiredHeader) An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.
```

I've already checked the documentation but it seems we're not missing any required header argument. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same code that you have provided and it's working fine for me without any error.

[image]

I have given some time in the `break_lease()` method and you can see the progress.

[image]

**Lease broken:**

[image]

Recheck the same code from different cluster and see if it's working. Also, try by adding the `"x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob"` header in it.

If it's still not working, use the connection string method as workaround.

```
con_str="<storage_account_connection_string>"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(con_str)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client("container1", "Table1.csv")
BlobLeaseClient(blob_client).break_lease()
```

[image]